# Accident Simulation without IVC

Tags: veins

I want to simulate a scenario where accident occurs but no intervehicle communication takes place.The accident occurs after 30 seconds of the entrance of a particular vehicle and the duration is of 30 seconds??

Comment: Please rephrase your post to state your question more clearly. Right now, I do not see any question in this post.

Comment: I wanted to know that in the example given in veins for erlangen city, is there a way through which I can disable the inter vehicle communication and only an accident occurs for 30 seconds ??

Comment: Is this question answered?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to disable IVC. However, you can do this in the [omnetpp.ini](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/examples/veins/omnetpp.ini) by using the `sendBeacons` parameter from [BaseWaveApplLayer](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.ned):

```
*.node[*].appl.sendBeacons = false
```

You can change the accident duration by using the corresponding parameter in the the [omnetpp.ini](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/examples/veins/omnetpp.ini):

```
*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentDuration = 30s
```